# Quitting to Game Over when player dies

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, adventure

So, I'm working on a python text-based game that I can share with my friends. I've got most of the game working, but I'm struggling with the game over portion for when a user selects certain commands. I'm not using pygame for this because I can't find a 64-bit version. Below is what I'm looking at. What do I put in the gameOver function to actually quit the game, or if the player wants, try again?

```
import time
import random
import sys

def searchAreas():
    print("1. Area1")
    print("2. Area2")
    print("3. Area3")
    print("4. Just give up")

def badResponse():
    print("Sorry, I don't understand " + search_area)

def gameOver():
    print("You decide to give up because life is too hard.")
    print("Would you like to try again?")
    player_choice = input("> ")
    if player_choice == "Yes":
        mainGame()
    elif player_choice == "No":
        print("# what goes here to quit the game?")
    else:
        badResponse()

def mainGame():
    search_area_options = ["1","2","3"]
    search_area = ""
    while search_area not in search_area_options:
        print("Where do you want to start looking?")
        searchAreas()
        search_area = str(input("> "))
        if search_area == "1":
            print("Text here")
        elif search_area == "2":
            print("Text here")
        elif search_area == "3":
            print("text here")
        elif search_area == "4":
            gameOver()
        else:
            badResponse()

mainGame()
```

When typing anything but the four options, or when going into the gameOver function, I'm seeing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 45, in <module>
    mainGame()
  File "./test.py", line 43, in mainGame
    badResponse()
  File "./test.py", line 14, in badResponse
    print("Sorry, I don't understand " + search_area)
NameError: name 'search_area' is not defined
```

Comment: Why not just exit(0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing games, more often than tradidional "backend" Python coding, we find the need for this pattern: from an intern function to "jump" to an outer function.

So in games, it will be common that from a function called from your mainloop you will want to go out of the mainloop and go to a place where the code setup the next game stage, or one that shows a game-over screen, and offers to start a new game.

Python has the "sys.exit" call that stops the program altogether, so, while you might call it from the code checking for the end-of-game condidions, that would quit your came program entirely, and not give the user the option to start a new match. (and if your game is on a graphic UI rather than a console "print and input" game, the already bad experience becomes catastrophic, as the game itself would just suddenly close with no traces).

So, while this could be managed with a "state variable" that could be set by these functions, and managed by the mainloop (in your case, the `while` statement in the `mainGame` function), that design is tedious and error-prone - it'd be something like:

```py
def mainGame(...):
   ...   
   game_over = False
   while not game_over:
       if search_area not in search_area_options:
            game_over = True
       ...
       if search_area == "4":
            game_over = True
```

So, note that with this design, if something changes the "game_over" flag to True,
no matter where, on the next iteration, the "while" condition will fail, and 
the program will naturally end the execution of your `mainGame` function - and
if there is no outside function handling a "play again?" screen, the program ends.

It is alright, and maybe the correct thing to do for a simple game like this.

But in more complex designs, your options in the main-loop my become more complicated  - you can call functions that could implement mini-games on their own, or the checkings thenselves might not be trivial - and, above all, 
there might be more than a "game over" condition to exit this main function, for example, a "winning" condition that would lead the game for the next stage.

In these cases, instead of book-keeping the game state in variables, you might want to make use of Python's Exception mechanism. 
Exceptions are a construct in the language that occurs naturally on a program error, which enables the program to either stop, or continue to run in a function "above" the place where the exception took place - if the programmer just includes the correct "try-except" clauses to catch the exception.

So, a complex game can take place, that can handle arbitrarily comples games, and still, through creating good-named exceptions and placing try-except clauses appropriately, it is easy to always know of where the execution will lead to - 
the skeleton for a more complex game using this strategy could be something along:

```py
# start

class BaseGameException(BaseException): pass

class ProgramExit(BaseGameException): pass

class GameOver(BaseGameException): pass

class MiniGameOver(BaseGameException): pass

class NextStage(BaseGameException): pass


def minigame():
    while True:
        # code for game-within-game mini game
        ...
        if some_condition_for_winning_main_game_stage:
            raise NextStage
        ...


def main_game(stage):
    # get data, scenarios, and variables as appropriate for the current stage
    while True:
        ...
        if some_condition_for_minigame:
            minigame()
        ...
        if condition_for_death:
            raise GameOver
        ...

def query_play_again():
    # print and get messag reponse on whether to play again
    ...
    if player_decided_to_quit:
        # This takes execution to outsude the "main_game_menu" function;
        raise ProgramExit


def main_game_menu():
    """Handle game start/play again/leatherboard screens"""
    stage = 1
    while True:
        # print welcome message, and prompt for game start
        try:
            main_game(stage)
        except NextStage:
            # print congratulations message, and prepare for next stage
            stage += 1
        except GameOver:
            # player died - print proper messages, leatherboard
            query_play_again()
            stage = 1
            # if the program returns here, just let the "while" restart the game

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main_game_menu()
    except ProgramExit:
        print("Goodbye!")
```

Answer (score 1):

To quit the script, you can use

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

As for your badResponse error: you are trying to use the variable search_area in the bad-response function, but that variable is defined in another function which means it has no access to it. You either have to pass search_area as a parameter to badResponse or make search_area a global variable (defined at the top, outside any function).

Answer (score 1):

In your function search_area doesn’t exist.

```
def badResponse():
    print("Sorry, I don't understand " + search_area)
```

You need to pass search_area into your function:

```
def badResponse(search_area):
    print("Sorry, I don't understand " + search_area)
```

When you want to call the function use:

```
badResponce(search_area)
```